# Blazor [Parameter] not update using @ref

Tags: properties, blazor, ref

I'm using .net6.0 Blazor razor library to create a component.

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop;
@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

<audio id="@Id" src="@Source" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

I use this component in a razor page using this :

```
<AudioPlayer     
    Id="reactorAudioElement1"
    Source="/audio/lion-roaring.ogg">
</AudioPlayer>
```

And everything is doing fine at this point.

But, if I try to use @ref like that,

```
<AudioPlayer 
    @ref=@_Jukebox2>
</AudioPlayer>
@code {
    private AudioPlayer _Jukebox2;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _Jukebox2 = new AudioPlayer()
        {
            Id="reactorAudioElement2",
            Source="/audio/Bleep_02.ogg"
        };
    }
}
```

nothing is set in the DOM.

But I can read data like this, and I cannot set it...

```
<AudioPlayer 
    @ref=@_Jukebox2
    Id="reactorAudioElement2"
</AudioPlayer>
@code {
    private AudioPlayer _Jukebox2;
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_Jukebox2.Id); //ok
        _Jukebox2.Source = "toto.mp3"; //doesn't do anything
    }
}
```

Adding a StateHasChanged(); is not working

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Shouldn't there be quotes? `@ref="@_Jukebox2"`?

Comment: don't know, I tested both, and no diff.

Answer (score 2):

Your component in DOM is created with this section of code, and your component will have valid @ref value

```
<AudioPlayer 
    @ref=@_Jukebox2
    Id="reactorAudioElement2"
</AudioPlayer>
```

but you are creating another object in code with this section of code

```
_Jukebox2 = new AudioPlayer()
        {
            Id="reactorAudioElement2",
            Source="/audio/Bleep_02.ogg"
        };
```

In above code you can create object, but can not have DOM reference

This part of code will create an element in DOM and set it's reference to _Jukebox2, will also set value of Source

```
 <AudioPlayer 
        @ref=@_Jukebox2
        Id="reactorAudioElement2"
        Source="@source"
    </AudioPlayer>

private string source="Source="/audio/Bleep_02.ogg"`;
```

And in code behind you should be able to access public methods or variable in  _Jukebox2  like this

```
_Jukebox.Source="toto.mp3";
```

If its not updating DOM then issue might be somewhere else

Comment: Thanks Surinder, but this was just a recopy mistake. I corrected it in the question. This is not the real issue.

Comment: Yann, I have updated my answer, please have a look at it

Comment: ok, but if I don't do a new AudioPlayer, but just, _Jukebox2.Source = "toto.mp3", this doesn't affect DOM. Meanwhile I use a <AudioPlayer 
    @ref=@_Jukebox2
    Source="@MySource"
</AudioPlayer> and then @Mysource="toto.mp3" in code, this will works